# Reverse-Search Option for Badges Missing

Tags: feature-request, badges

Can we readd the feature where we can see *how* to earn badges in Stack Exchange? Since a recent update I can't find it.

Comment: See the bottom quote in the question to find the link you're looking for.

Comment: Re *"how to earn badges"*: Do you mean *the progress* towards them? And/or *the next badge to earn*? No, not the last one. It is still up: *"Next badge"* on the "Activity" tab on the user profile.

Comment: I mean the progress towards them *and* being able to see the next badges you can earn.

Comment: Are you referring to [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6fhp.png)?

Comment: Because that still works.

Comment: Where is it? I can't find it.